# MongoDB Replication Info Results

Tags: mongodb, replication, database-replication, mongodb-cluster

I want to understand the following:

1. First-Third execution of db.printSlaveReplicationInfo() results to “0 secs (0 hrs) behind the primary”
2. Fourth execution of db.printSlaveReplicationInfo() results to “4 secs (0 hrs) behind the primary”
3. Fifth and Sixth execution of db.printSlaveReplicationInfo() results to “2 secs (0 hrs) behind the primary”
4. Seventh-Tenth execution of db.printSlaveReplicationInfo() results to “0 secs (0 hrs) behind the primary”

Why is the lag always changing even if there are no changes or queries executed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are *always* writes being executed.

If nothing else has been written for 10 seconds, the primary node will write a no-op into the oplog to make sure replication is functioning.

Comment: Hello Joe, thank you very much for your response.
When you say "always", this means that aside from clients executing queries to MongoDB, there are other "writes" that triggers the replication every after a few seconds. Is that correct?

Comment: yes, the mongod node will automatically generate a write after 10 seconds idle

Comment: is this behavior configurable? Like can we change the 10 second timeout or refresh rate to start/check replication again?

Comment: I haven't seen documentation that mentions it being modified, but the inline help shows a parameter called `periodicNoopIntervalSecs`

Comment: I'll check it Joe, thank you very much for you response.